# tz aware string pd.to_datetime sometimes returns datetime instead of timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

- I have the following pandas dataframe, and the data is in str format.
- The data has a change in time offset between rows 1 & 2 because of daylight savings.

```
>>> data
                   timestamp
0  2017-03-10 14:58:51-06:00
1  2017-03-10 14:59:59-06:00
2  2017-03-13 08:30:00-05:00
3  2017-03-13 08:30:01-05:00

>>> type(data.loc[0, 'timestamp'])
<class 'str'>
```

- I am trying to convert it to a tz aware timestamp. However, when I convert all the data it comes back as datetime.

```
>>> data['converted'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])
>>> data['type'] = data['converted'].apply(type)
>>> data
                   timestamp                  converted                         type
0  2017-03-10 14:58:51-06:00  2017-03-10 14:58:51-06:00  <class 'datetime.datetime'>
1  2017-03-10 14:59:59-06:00  2017-03-10 14:59:59-06:00  <class 'datetime.datetime'>
2  2017-03-13 08:30:00-05:00  2017-03-13 08:30:00-05:00  <class 'datetime.datetime'>
3  2017-03-13 08:30:01-05:00  2017-03-13 08:30:01-05:00  <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

- When I only convert a portion of it without the offset time change it comes back as intended.

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(data.loc[2:, 'timestamp'])
2   2017-03-13 08:30:00-05:00
3   2017-03-13 08:30:01-05:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-300)]
```

- It also works when I convert it row wise with apply

```
>>> data['converted'] = data['timestamp'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
>>> data['type'] = data['converted'].apply(type)
>>> data
                   timestamp                  converted                                               type
0  2017-03-10 14:58:51-06:00  2017-03-10 14:58:51-06:00  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
1  2017-03-10 14:59:59-06:00  2017-03-10 14:59:59-06:00  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
2  2017-03-13 08:30:00-05:00  2017-03-13 08:30:00-05:00  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
3  2017-03-13 08:30:01-05:00  2017-03-13 08:30:01-05:00  <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
```

- Why is there a difference?
- Is there a way I can covert all of the data and get timestamp format without using apply?

Comment: as soon as you have timestamps with different UTC offsets (or time zones) in one column, the dtype of the whole column will be of type 'object' - no matter if you convert the whole column (your first example) or element-wise (your second example) from string to_datetime. Not sure though *why* you get instances from different classes in those two examples.

Comment: side note: another way could be to parse everything to UTC, using `pd.to_datetime(col, utc=True)`.

Comment: Using the utc=True flag allowed me to load the data into the desired format. I then used tz_convert to change it back to the original timezone. Thanks!

Comment: great, haven't thought of this ^^ (as long as you know the time zone).